# RSA sign base64 or original data

Tags: base64, rsa, signing

I'm building a client (C#)/server (PHP) application in which the server signs a message with RSA and the client verifies the message. So far so good. 
I'm using HTTPS/JSON as protocol for the communication and therefore I have to encode binary data in the message as base64.

My question here is: What's best practice? To sign the base64 encoded data or the original binary data?

Are there any positives or negatives for doing one of them?

King regards.

Comment: As gusto2 said, it doesn't matter. There will be a slight performance penalty for signing/verifying the base64 data versus the more compact bytes. The best practice is probably to find some standard for the type of information you are communicating and adhere to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question here is: What's best practice? To sign the base64 encoded data or the original binary data?

At the end - it doesn't matter. The signature ensures integrity of the signed data regardless they are encoded or not.